# Conversion failing when changing join constraint from list of varchars to subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to update a procedure we run by switching out a list of static varchars within an `IN` statement (which is in a join condition) to use a subquery instead.  However, I'm getting an error saying `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Normal' to data type int.`

I know that means somewhere in the query I'm trying to convert the value 'Normal' to an int, but in this query there's not a place where anything should be an int - it's all varchar or datetime, and the subquery returns the same values as the former static list of varchars.  Furthermore, there's not a place anywhere in my dataset with the value "Normal", which is what really confuses me.

Has anyone else dealt with something like this before?

**EDIT:**
Here's the code (reduced to just show the pieces that are causing the error):

```
select * from #tempTable
    left join dbo.v_Lookup_Assumptions Assumptions on 
    case when Group3 in 
    --('Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3') 
    (Select lookupdetail_name  from lookupDetail)
    then Group3 else Group2 end =Assumptions.Sector2
    and AsOfDate between Assumptions.StartDate and Assumptions.EndDate
    and ShortName = Assumptions.AssumptionShortName
```

I can comment out the subquery and uncomment the list of values and it works.  Also, if I don't run the "ShortName" constraint when I'm using the subquery, it works (though doesn't give the expected results, as you might expect).  All join constraints are either varchar or date.

In addition, I added 'Normal' to the list of static values and it ran as expected.  I also updated the subquery to `SELECT 'Value1' from lookupDetail` and it failed.

**EDIT2:**
And this makes no sense, but if I limit the original `#tempTable` to 2080 records, the new subquery syntax works.  However, if I let it go to 2081 records it fails - regardless of the dataset.  In other words, as I change the dates around so I get different data each time through and limit `#tempTable` to 2080 records, this new syntax works just fine.  Change it to 2081 records and it fails.  If I run through the 2081 record dataset and filter with a WHERE clause, I can get every row in the 2081 record to display as long as it's not all 2081 at the same time.

Comment: I think that this is one of those times where actually reading the "before" and "after" code could help a little

Comment: I think I have ran into something similar before. @lamak is right we would need to see the code to help.

Comment: Normal has to be in there somewhere, lurking...

Comment: @scsimon - agreed, it seems like has to be in there somewhere, but I just can't find it.  I did a `SELECT *` of all the data, dumped it into Excel and couldn't find it anywhere, even as a part of any of the fields.  I know there's something I'm missing here.

Comment: can you provide some sample data? I'm surprised that your `IN` is working properly... you should need a split function to take the values of your subquery `(Select lookupdetail_name  from lookupDetail)` and put them into a comma seperated list. I'm not sold that your error is in this part of the code, but you may have errors here as well.

Comment: That syntax (ie. just selecting the column, not making it into a comma-separated list) works for me elsewhere, and is used for examples on the [MSDN page for IN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx)

Comment: Also, unfortunately I can't provide any of the data, it's confidential, internal-only info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the execution plan was changing when the total number of records would exceed 2080, and was implicitly converting a varchar field to an int.  I grabbed the XML query plan for the small dataset from SQL Server Profiler and forced the larger dataset query to use it with `OPTION (USE PLAN '<Insert XML Query Plan Here />')`.